# Choosing Between Registered Controller and HttpClient.SendJsonAsync for Data Access Performance

Tags: model-view-controller, blazor, .net-8.0

I’m exploring data access methods in my Blazor project and comparing the usage of a registered controller with method calls against using `HttpClient.SendJsonAsync` to invoke server-side methods.

What factors should I consider when choosing between these approaches in terms of performance, maintainability, and best practices? Are there specific scenarios where one method is preferable over the other, and do they have notable differences in terms of performance in a Blazor project? Your insights and recommendations would be valuable.